# Error while passing arguments to Pyspark Script in Azure data Factory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

I am running a PySpark script from Azure Data Factory. 
I have mentioned the arguments in the given section under Script/Jar as below.

[image]

The arguments are a Key Value pair.
Arguments are being submitted fine as seen below.

```
--arg '--APP_NAME ABC' --arg '--CONFIG_FILE_PATH wasbs://ABC --arg '--OUTPUT_INFO wasbs://XYZ
```

When the pipeline is executed I am getting the below Error.

```
usage: Data.py [-h] --CONFIG_FILE_PATH CONFIG_FILE_PATH --OUTPUT_INFO
                      OUTPUT_INFO --ACTION_CODE ACTION_CODE --RUN_ID RUN_ID
                      --APP_NAME APP_NAME --JOB_ID JOB_ID --TASK_ID TASK_ID
                      --PCS_ID PCS_ID --DAG_ID DAG_ID
Data.py: error: argument --CONFIG_FILE_PATH is required.
```

Comment: have you provoided any value for that parameter

Comment: @GaurangShah, Yes --APP_NAME is the key and ABC is the value. i removed the values to paste the image here.

Comment: it seems like only one argument is being passed `--arg '--APP_NAME ABC'`

Comment: Total 9 Arguments were passed. I only mentioned few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can passing arguments to Pyspark Script in Azure data Factory.

[image]

**Code:**

```
{
    "name": "SparkActivity",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Spark1",
                "type": "HDInsightSpark",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "rootPath": "adftutorial/spark/script",
                    "entryFilePath": "WordCount_Spark.py",
                    "arguments": [
                        "--input-file",
                        "wasb://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/data",
                        "--output-file",
                        "wasb://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/results"
                    ],
                    "sparkJobLinkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "HDInsight",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

**WALKTHROUGH for passing arguments in ADF:**

[image]

**Some of the example for passing the parameters in Azure Data Factory:**

```
{
    "name": "SparkSubmit",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Submit a spark job",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "HDInsightMapReduce",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "className": "com.adf.spark.SparkJob",
                    "jarFilePath": "libs/spark-adf-job-bin.jar",
                    "jarLinkedService": "StorageLinkedService",
                    "arguments": [
                        "--jarFile",
                        "libs/sparkdemoapp_2.10-1.0.jar",
                        "--jars",
                        "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-azure-2.7.1.2.3.3.0-3039.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar",
                        "--mainClass",
                        "com.adf.spark.demo.Demo",
                        "--master",
                        "yarn-cluster",
                        "--driverMemory",
                        "2g",
                        "--driverExtraClasspath",
                        "/usr/lib/hdinsight-logging/*",
                        "--executorCores",
                        "1",
                        "--executorMemory",
                        "4g",
                        "--sparkHome",
                        "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client",
                        "--connectionString",
                        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<YOUR_ACCOUNT>;AccountKey=<YOUR_KEY>",
                        "input=wasb://input@<YOUR_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/data",
                        "output=wasb://output@<YOUR_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/results"
                    ]
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "input"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "output"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "OldestFirst",
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "retry": 1
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Spark Launcher",
                "description": "Submits a Spark Job",
                "linkedServiceName": "HDInsightLinkedService"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2015-11-16T00:00:01Z",
        "end": "2015-11-16T23:59:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```